# POST works on localhost but not live server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

There are lots of similar questions asked in this forum and none of them seems close to the issue i am facing. I am a novice in Jquery and JQM. I am recently building a phonegap hybrid app using jquery mobile with backend php.

I had created a mobile number registration page on local host where as the data is being captured and inserted in db succesfully through backend php.

Now the issue is that, while trying the same on live server, i am getting failed message with the same code i am using on my localhost. I am unable to understand what wen missing. Request to look into the code mentioned below and suggest what is missing.

```
//Jquery Mobile form HTML Code:
<div data-role="page" id="signup" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>SIGN-UP</h1>
        <a href="menu" data-icon="grid">Menu</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Mobile Number" data-role="text" id="otpmobilo">
                <input type="button" value="Get Code" id="otpsubmits">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="b">
        <h6>&copy; Footer Details</h6>
    </div>
</div>

//Jquery Code:
$("#otpsubmits").click(function () {
    var mobile = $("#otpmobilo").val();
    var dataString = "phone=" + mobile;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php-code2/rand2.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (response) {
            if (response == "success") {
                alert("Success!!!");
                //displayOtp();
            } else if (response == "failed") {
                alert("Failed");
            }
        }
    });
});

//PHP Code:
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
include'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['phone']))
{
$mobile=$_POST['phone'];
$digits = 4;
$rand = rand(pow(10, $digits-1), pow(10, $digits)-1);
$otp = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `users`(`mobile`,`verifyCode`) VALUES ($mobile,$rand)");
if($otp){
echo "success";
}else{
echo "failed";
}
}
?>
```

But when i try to display data from db, i am able to pull data through get method and able to display data as required on the page. Seems the issue is with post method in json ajax which i am not sure. Need your help in resolving this issue.

Comment: You have asked the same question and got no answer. Obviously, you have something wrong with your PHP code or server-side; *check error log* on your server. Your issue isn't related to jQM at all. If the same code works on localhost, it should work on live server. Side note: drop `mysqli` and use `PDO` instead http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Yes since i received no response, i had posted the same once again. I had provided all the code which i am using on my localhost and are working fine. But POST is not working on live server whereas GET is working fine. I knew there is something wrong and hence posted here for some clarity what went wrong. Hope you understand my concern. i had even provided my php code so that experts can suggest what went wrong.

Comment: log and post here raw request (can be obtained from file_get_contents('php://input') );

Comment: I am pretty confident that the problem lies in the path set in the Ajax call.